# exec on a remote machine and store output

Tags: php, ssh, exec

I want to execute a command on a remote machine and store the out of that command in a variable using php

Here is what i tried

```
$command = 'exec("whoami")';
$connection = ssh2_connect($ip,$port); 
ssh2_auth_password($connection,$user,$pass); 
$test = ssh2_shell($connection,$command); 
echo $test;
```

According to me $test should output `root`
However nothing is return , I am sure i am missing something.....
`php-pecl-ssh2` is already installed and no error is returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your command is incorrect :

```
$command = 'whoami';
```

And you should also add this 2 lines to the end to get your output :

```
if ( $connection = ssh2_connect($ip,$port) ) {
    echo 'Error occured while connecting to server via ssh';
}
if (!ssh2_auth_password($connection,$user,$pass)) {
    echo 'Error occured while authenticating via ssh';
}
if(!$test = ssh2_shell($connection,$command)){
    echo 'Error occured while executing remote command via ssh';
} else {
    stream_set_blocking($test, true);
    echo stream_get_contents($test);
}
```

Comment: I tried it and the page don't seem to reload...do `php-pecl-ssh2` need to be install on the remote machine as well

Comment: i have already set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in the php file so that any error get displayed but here the page isn't loading

Comment: Ok, I've changed something for you to trace the mistake.